# I want to reboot the system using puppet by using reboot resource but it is throwing error like "Invalid resource type: Reboot"?."

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent

I want to reboot the system using puppet by using reboot resource but it is throwing error like "Invalid resource type: Reboot"?.

Is there any need modules that I need to install??. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

PuppetLabs provide a [reboot module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/reboot).

Install it on your Puppet Master using the command-line:

```
$ puppet module install puppetlabs-reboot
```

Then call it in your manifests:

```
package { 'SomeModule':
  ensure          => installed,
  source          => '\\server\share\some_installer.exe',
  install_options => ['/Passive', '/NoRestart'],
}
reboot { 'after':
  subscribe       => Package['SomeModule'],
}
```

See the [documentation](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/reboot) for a better understanding of how it works.